# Recently upgraded iPadOS. It seems my ability to screen record is now reduced to 1/5th the duration. Any fixes?

Tags: ios, ipad, photos.app, ipados, screen-recording

Before the upgrade I was running iOS 12.2.2, which let me record on high quality for two hours of live music or video conferencing without problems (1.5GB was good for for 30 minutes of recording). This worked extremely well.

After the upgrade, 1.5GB now gets burned up in about 6 and a half minutes (cough..). To account for what's going on, I looked into the bitrate, which shows recordings previously averaged around 7,000 kbps, whereas they're now being made at 31,000 kbps. For comparison, I gauged YouTube to be streaming content to this device (an iPad pro) at less than 1,000 kbps..

For the sake of argument, if content streaming to my device is coming through at around 1,000 kbps, am I really being required to record at a quality setting 31x higher than that? I haven't been able to find a setting to change it, which feels a lot like having a camera that's saving 3-gigapixel pictures as 90-gigapixel images :/.

This is more than just an inconvenience, it's become completely destructive to the work I could previously get done. For long recordings, previously I could "set it and forget it", but now I need to be constantly breaking up streams into segments and moving them off the device while a feed is in progress. Reordering and re-encoding these large blocks back into 7,000 kbps segments is cumbersome and time consuming. Seeing the final quality come out worse than what I was originally getting in iOS 12.2.2 (I assume due to the re-encoding) is just pouring salt in an open wound. I don't like to think negatively, but someone floated the idea that this is just a bloat strategy for Apple to cause users to use more cloud storage. I truly hope someone here proves this wrong and saves my sanity.

Now don't get me wrong, I like having the **option** to record at 31,000 kbps. I'm all for the idea of having such awesome ability at my fingertips. But isn't there some setting, a fix, or even a 3rd party app that I can use to get the more reasonable bitrate and high level of quality that was previously available? I understand I don't have the option to downgrade iOS to a previous version.